# Having Schengen visa for Germany. Transiting through Paris is possible without having transit visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, paris, air-france

I am going to Germany (at Hannover) next month, with a Schengen visa (multiple entry) for Germany for a week. But I want to explore Paris for a while as CDG airport is not so far from many tourist places, such as the Eiffel Tower, etc. I am planning to book tickets via Air France having a layover over 10 hrs at CDG Airport so that I can have some time to explore and catch the next flight to Hannover after that.
So my questions are...

Q1. Do I need a transit visa for my purpose? or what kind of transit visa do I need?

Q2. If I only want to be at CDG Airport during layover time to explore the airport area only, then also do I need a transit visa?

Comment: You will have passport control only in Paris, not in Germany.

Comment: So my immigration will be done at CDG paris instead of HAJ Hannover right without any problem as I am holding a valid Schengen visa for germany for a week?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1 and Q2: You don't need a transit visa. As a general rule you may cross any Schengen border with visa issued by any Schengen
country and you have rights to visit other Schengen countries.

Comment: You are welcome. If you need more details check official European union Schengen, Borders & Visas/Visa policy FAQ publication: https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the Link. I got several valuable information. As my purpose of visit is on Business Visa (Schengen) to Germany i.e. not with a tourist visa so I hope I will not get into problems during immigration check that I will not have been asked why I availed such ticket transiting from another Schengen country when there are other Airlines available as example Lufthansa as I am on a Business Trip. 
Please help me to have your valuable response. Thanks!

Comment: You are allowed to enter Schengen area in France. Nobody can decide which flights you should take instead of you. You can even take flight to Paris, thank continue your trip with train for example. In your case difference is that you will have passport control in France instead of Germany, like @phoog said in the comment above.